# What is this tool called in qt designer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

[image]

> what is this tool called and how to make it using qt designer?it is commonly used in other softwares to resize width and height by pressing it.

Comment: That's a QSplitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a splitter, or, in Qt terms, a [QSplitter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html).

You cannot directly add it to an UI, because to Designer it acts as a layout manager (even if it technically is not, since it inherits from QFrame, so it's a widget).

You can create a splitter by selecting two or more widgets that are considered *siblings* (they are children of the same parent, or all selected widgets are children of items that have the same parent), right click on any of them, and select "Layout horizontally/vertically in Splitter" from the "Lay out" menu.

Note that:

- since QSplitter is a container (similarly to a layout dragged from the *Widget Box*), you also need to create a parent layout (if none exists) and add the splitter to that parent layout;
- QSplitter can only add QWidget based classes, so Designer creates "invisible" widgets when adding layouts to a splitter, and those widgets cannot be directly accessed by Designer, so if you need to add multiple widgets to a single "page" of a splitter, it's usually better to group them into a layout managed by a container (a basic QWidget will suffice) and add *that* container to the splitter;